# SQLAlchemy DatabaseError - catching trigger exception in unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, unicode, sqlalchemy

I have this module running on python 2.7 with SQLAlchemy-0.8.3

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, SmallInteger, String
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
from sqlalchemy.types import CHAR
from dict_app import *

db=create_engine('mysql://{}:{}@{}/{}?charset=utf8'.\
    format(Glob.user,Glob.passwd,Glob.host,Glob.dbName))
session=scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                    autoflush=False,
                                    bind=db))
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    id = Column(CHAR(5), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(45), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, id=None, name=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{}".format(self.name)

def validate():
    try:
        session.commit()
        print("The model has been recorded on the disk")
        return 0
    except Exception as e:
        #print(u"%s" % unicode(e.message).encode("utf-8"))
        print(unicode(e.message).encode("utf-8"))
        session.rollback()
        return e
```

On the database, I have defined a trigger that control that the name is not already used :

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TRIGGER trig_ins_user BEFORE INSERT ON User
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE nbUser integer;
  DECLARE specialty CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
  DECLARE msg varchar(255);
  SELECT count(*) INTO nbUser FROM User
    WHERE name = NEW.name;
  IF nbUser > 0 THEN
      SET msg = CONCAT('Il existe déjà un utilisateur répondant au nom de ', NEW.name); 
      SIGNAL specialty SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
  END IF;
END$$
```

In order to test this trigger, i run this code :

```
>>> u1 = User('15001', 'tux')
>>> session.add(u1)
>>> validate()
The model has been recorded on the disk
0
>>> u2 = User('15002', 'tux')
>>> session.add(u2)
>>> err = validate()
(OperationalError) (1644, 'Il existe d\xc3\xa9j\xc3\xa0 un utilisateur r\xc3\xa9pondant au nom de tux')
>>> err
OperationalError("(OperationalError) (1644, 'Il existe d\\xc3\\xa9j\\xc3\\xa0 un utilisateur r\\xc3\\xa9pondant au nom de tux')",)
>>> id(err)
22987712
>>> type(err)
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError'>
>>>
```

so I want to deal with message from trigger written with accent...

The Mysql server is working fine, this is a paste made with a mysql console :

```
mysql> insert into User values ('15001', 'tux');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert into User values ('15002', 'tux');
ERROR 1644 (45000): Il existe déjà un utilisateur répondant au nom de tux
mysql>
```

Comment: I know, I could use unique=True in the User Model instead of the trigger. In fact, it is just a first test, I want to test uniqness for (first name, last name, ...)

Comment: There is no encoding issue through Python 3 with the mysql-connector